# Redactor: image upload not being displayed in text editor

Tags: internet-explorer-11, redactor, redactor.js

I am using the Redactor Text Editor which is giving me an error.

When I try to insert an image by clicking on the 'Browse' button in the 'Insert Image' modal in Internet Explorer 11 the image is not inserted into the text area.

I am getting the following errors:

> SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object

and:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

However, if I drag and drop an image in the the 'Drop File Here' section of the Insert Image modal then the image is inserted into the text editor as expected.

The issue above only occurs in IE 11. It is working fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

I am asking this question on the off chance that someone has seen this bug before. Does anyone know what is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to my issue.

I was using version 9.2.6 of Redactor and I simply updated to the latest version. The error was with the `redactor.js` file and not with my code.

The second error message I specified in the question above may appear as:

> TypeError: rawString.match(...) is null

in older or different browsers but I would assume that the same solution applies.